# Creating a rule based approach to identify Stock Out products

Tags: time-series, prediction

I am trying to build a Stock Out Predictive Model based on input variables such as:

Sell In Unit: Units per month sold to wholesaler by manufacturer

Sell Out Unit: Units per month sold by wholesaler to retailer

Stock Unit: Stock  (product left) with Retailer at the end of each month.

I have around 15k distinct retailers across 13 months of data for each. The problem is to develop the Stocked Out retailers at first as I am running out of ideas to create 0 (does not Stock out) and 1 (will Stock out).

I am fiddling around the idea of using EWMA control charts at 3 months or 6 months level and for any retailer that falls under the Lower chart will be categorized as Stock Out. As I have around 15k retailers trying to run a function is becoming tedious.

Should I continue with EWMA which will be time consuming or are there better ways to do this